# "Double subscript" error in "align" environment

Tags: align, subscripts

I saw some questions about "double subscript" but I have a weird situation. I have the following parts in my code:

[image: line 44-48]

and...

[image: line 56-59]

I have used almost the same subscripts in both of them, but the latter one gives a "double subscript" error while the first one works fine. What am I missing there? What is the reason for that error?

Here is my error bar:

[image: error bar]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have `h_{j)}_0` that qualifies as double subscript.

Comment: Do you wish `h_{j_0}`?

Comment: Replace `h_{j)}_0` with `{h_{j)}}_0`. The structure `a_b_c` is causing the error. Add brackets.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. The problem was really about braces. I did exactly what @anderstood said and it pefectly worked!

Comment: @anderstood -- your comment contains the answer to the question.  please make it into an actual answer so that this doesn't have to be chased down in the "answer the unanswered" session next saturday.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is caused by the improper double subscript `h_{j)}_0` (of type `a_b_c`). Add brackets to help latex discriminate between `a_{b_c}` or `{a_b}_c`.

[image]

Note that is similar to the ambiguity in maths: is 2^3^4 supposed to mean 8^4 or 2^81?

Comment: i think you are expecting the formulas to be rendered as they are on the math forum -- where mathjax is used.  mathjax is *not* used in tex.sx, since it is usually the case that people here want to see the source, not the output.  output has to be inserted as a (png) image.