# Getting a double subscript error - Code review

Tags: errors, subscripts

I'm getting a double subscript error from the following simple code:

```
Consider a sample drawn from the population consisting of the set $\{ e_{1}, e_{2},\cdots, e_{n} \} $. This sample can be selected in any order, i.e $e_{1},e_{2},..._e_{n}$ or $e_{4},e_{8},e_{n-1},...e_{n}$. This implies there are $n!$ different orders for the sample.
```

As far I can read it and I checked it twice all of my curly braces are assigned correctly. Is there something else I may be doing wrong?

Comment: You have `_e_{n}`. I suppose you mean `e_{n}`

Comment: That did the trick. Would you like to put a "formal answer so I can give you the points?

Comment: You have `..._e_{n}`; use `\dots` instead of `...` and also a comma: `e_{1},e_{2},\dots,e_{n}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Double subscript" error in "align" environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225867/double-subscript-error-in-align-environment)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments

Comment: I have no issue with this being done.

Comment: Note that the error will show the offending section of code, and place a line break right at the error point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `_e_n{n}` should be just `e_{n}`. Also, `...` should be `\cdots` (`\dots` if you want the dots at the baseline.)